# Message: Undefined index: childmenus

Tags: arrays, indexing

Hi i have some problem with array in codeigniter, how i can pass array to the view, here is the code doesn't work.

Model :

```
 public function get_all()
    {           

        $query = $this->db->get('category');
        $result = $query->result_array();                      
        foreach( $result as $key => $row )
        {

          $query = $this->db->get_where('categorysub',   array('categoryID'=>$row['categoryID']));

            $row['childmenus'] = $query->result_array();
            $result[$key] = $row;

        }            
        return $result;            
    }
```

Controller :

```
$this->load->model(array('mcategory','mcategorysub'));
    $data['title']= 'Detail Kategori';
    $data[] = array(
            'nestedmenu' => $this->mcategory->get_all());

    $data['nestedmenu'] = array($data);
    $this->load->view($this->template, $data);
```

View :

```
   foreach($nestedmenu as $nestedmenu_type)
{

    echo "<h2>" . $nestedmenu_type['name'] . "</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";        
    foreach($nestedmenu_type['childmenus'] as $childmenu)
    {        
        echo "<li>" . $childmenu['name'] . "</li>";
    }        
    echo "</ul>";

}
```

the program should show result like this :

```
Menu 1
     menu 1a
     menu 1b
     menu 1c
Menu 2
     menu 2a
     menu 2b
......
```

but actually result error like this :

MENU 1

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: childmenus
Filename: admin/vcategory_read.php
Line Number: 34

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/vcategory_read.php

Line Number: 34

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it. your `$query->result_array()` returns an resource. Which cannot be used as a input for a foreach.